# Failed to enumerate processes: unable to handle 64-bit processes due to build configuration

Tags: frida

**Error Message:** **Failed to enumerate processes: unable to handle 64-bit processes due to build configuration** 
I try to use a frida. 
Command is **frida-ps -U** but i failed and got a error message. 
When I used a Android Virtual Device with android studio, I succeded this command.
But i use a USB and failed.

My device is Pixel 4a.
I install **frida-server-15.1.17-android-arm** in pixel 4a device. 
And I turn on USB debugging in pixel 4a. **python version: 3.10.0**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt7VW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have downloaded the wrong version of Frida server. "arm" means ARM 32bit.

Your phone is an Android 64 bit device (ARMv8a) which means that the majority of all processes and apps are 64bit binaries. Thus you need the latest arm64 version of Frida server: [frida-server-15.1.27-android-arm64](https://github.com/frida/frida/releases/download/15.1.27/frida-server-15.1.27-android-arm64.xz).